# what is the most pythonic way to split a 2d array to arrays of each row?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function foo that returns an array with the shape (1000, 2)
how can I split it to two arrays a(1000) and b(1000)
I'm looking for something like this:

```
a;b = foo()
```

I'm looking for an answer that can easily generalize to the case in which the shape is (1000, 5) or so.

Comment: Talking about a python `list` or a numpy array?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I suppose the default is python list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transpose and unpack?

```
a, b = foo().T
```

---

```
>>> a, b = np.arange(20).reshape(-1, 2).T
>>> a
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
>>> b
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

Answer (score 7):

The `zip(*...)` idiom transposes a traditional more-dimensional Python `list`:

```
x = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

# get columns    
a, b = zip(*x)   # zip(*foo())
# a, b = map(list, zip(*x))  # if you prefer lists over tuples
a
# (1, 3, 5)

# get rows
a, b, c = x
a
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.hsplit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit).

```
x = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
np.hsplit(x, x.shape[1])
```

This returns a list of subarrays.  Note that in the case of a 2d input, the subarrays will be shape (n, 1).  Unless you wrap a function around it to squeeze them to 1d:

```
def split_1d(arr_2d):
    """Split 2d NumPy array on its columns."""
    split = np.hsplit(arr_2d, arr_2d.shape[1])
    split = [np.squeeze(arr) for arr in split]
    return split

a, b, c, d = split_1d(x)

a
# array([0, 4, 8])

d
# array([ 3,  7, 11])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use list comprehensions, e.g.

```
(a,b)=([i[0] for i in mylist],[i[1] for i in mylist])
```

To generalise you could use a comprehension within a comprehension:

```
(a,b,c,d,e)=([row[i] for row in mylist] for i in range(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using `zip` function like:

```
def foo(mylist):
   return zip(*mylist)
```

Now call `foo` with as much dimension as you have in mylist, and it would do the requisite like:

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
a, b = foo(mylist)
# a = (1, 3, 5)
# b = (2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl provided this exact answer a full 5 minutes ago, why duplicate it?

Comment: @BradSolomon Oh, I didn't see it earlier. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a little nuts, but if you want to assign different letters to each sub-array in your array, and do so for any number of sub-arrays (up to 26 because alphabet), you could do:

```
import string
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)  # get all of the lower-case letters
arr_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(letters, foo())}
```

or more simply (for the last line):

```
arr_dict = dict(zip(letters, foo()))
```

Then you can access each individual element as `arr_dict['a']` or `arr_dict['b']`. This feels a little mad-scientist-ey to me, but I thought it was fun.

Comment: you are crazy:))

Comment: `dict(zip(letters, foo()))`

Comment: @BradSolomon oh yeah, forgot you can do it that way too. I'll add it, thanks.