# What is the most pythonic way to split a 3d array to 2d arrays with different second indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function foo that returns an array with the shape (1000, 3, 1000)
how can I split it to three arrays a(1000, 1000) and b(1000, 1000) and c(1000, 1000)
I'm looking for something like this:

```
a,b,c = foo()[:,*,:]
```

that will result in a,b,c equal to:

```
res = foo()
a = res[:,0,:]
b = res[:,1,:]
c = res[:,2,:]
```

Comment: your question is not clear and plz show your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe any of the following will work:

```
numpy.split(foo(), 3, axis=1)
numpy.hsplit(foo(),3)
list(numpy.swapaxes(foo(), 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this shoud work:

```
a,b,c = np.rollaxis(foo(), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353363/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-split-a-2d-array-to-arrays-of-each-row):

```
def foo():
    return np.ones((1000, 3, 1000))

a, b, c = [np.squeeze(arr) for arr in np.hsplit(foo(), foo().shape[1])]

for arr in [a, b, c]:
    print(arr.shape)
# (1000, 1000)
# (1000, 1000)
# (1000, 1000)
```

Without `np.squeeze` you'll get shapes of (1000, 1, 1000).